# Passing a vector by reference and changing its values in a range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, reference

I'm trying to change the values of a vector by doing something similar to the following function:

```
vector<int> Question2_Part3(vector<int> &v){

    for(auto elem : v){
        elem *= 2;
        cout << elem << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    return v;
}
```

Is this possible? I know that in my for loop, it is the value of `elem` that is changing. Can I have the same output while also changing the values in `v` and still use a range-based for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible but use a reference

```
for (auto &elem : v) {
    elem *= 2;
    cout << elem << " ";
}
```

This is also more efficient as it avoids copying each vector element to a variable. Actually if you didn't want to change the elements you should do

```
for (const auto &elem : v) {
    cout << elem << " ";
}
```

[More details](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: Thank you! I don't think I quite understood range-based for loops correctly to be able to spot that.